# How to apply keyboard accessibility when dropdown items are span tags?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag2.0

I'm having a hard time with a custom dropdown menu I made. I'm trying to make it keyboard accessible, but I'm not having much luck with the listbox option. I'm following the instructions I find under WCAG pages, but I'm not having any luck. Here's one of the dropdowns on my page:

```
<ul class="custom__options dropdown story-selector" id="storyFilter">
  <li class="custom__option selected" data-type="all" tabindex="0">All</li>
  <li class="custom__option" data-type="news" tabindex="0">News and media</li>
  <li class="custom__option" data-type="analysis" tabindex="0">Analysis</li>
  <li class="custom__option" data-type="press" tabindex="0">Press releases</li>
</ul>
```

Here's a working **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/r3hab/pen/ZEKEGYx?editors=1010)** to play with.

Comment: There are loads of things you need to do here, how much are you able to change the markup? For example, can we swap the `<div><span>` for `<ul><li>`, Also need to see your JS really to see if you have implemented arrow keys, home, end etc. Can you turn this into a snippet / jsfiddle / codepen and let us know what bits you are struggling with as at the moment I would just suggest following https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/listbox/listbox-collapsible.html to get a better understanding.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie - I've updated the OP with a Codepen. I have full control over the code and I've already changed the Codepen to reflect the `<ul><li>` format. I've also included the JS.

Comment: Great stuff, I will have a look later for you and put together a list of actions to do (unless someone else answers first!)

Comment: @GrahamRitchie - Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Good as far as it goes. (Codepen differs from the code posted above at time of writing). The "listbox" semantic is fine here, "select" might be just as good or better, but yes, the "children" in each case need role "option", so that's all good. The thing that opens the popup needs to respond to the keyboard (SPACE/ENTER), and then there are two ways to manage focus inside the popup, both using arrow keys. They are described at https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#managingfocus SPACE/ENTER will select an option, and ESC should close the popup without changing the selection further.

Answer (score 0):

Your Codepen example uses WAI-ARIA attributes but have missing roles and expected keyboard behaviours.

In order to be accessible, all elements must have a minimum of a role and a name.

Your role sets a promise to the user of what kind of element the thing is and sets an expectation of how that thing will behave. Consider a role of "slider". In that single word, you've conveyed a lot of information to the user as to what that component is and how it would behave.

The name helps the user to understand the purpose of the element. The name of a volume slide would be "Volume".

Related attributes and properties are typically applied to one element, or are implied through coded relationships (using aria-labelledby for example). You would not do the following in HTML, for example:

```
<span alt="My image's text alternative">
<img src="image.png">
</span>
```

Yet I see things like this often for ARIA `menubar` implementations:

```
<li role="menuitem">
<a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">Home</a>
</li>
```

There are options here, but with similar markup, the following would be more appropriate for the interactive menuitem:

```
<li role="none">
<button role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true">Home</button>
</li>
```

It's best to use HTML elements with the closest semantics to what you are hoping to achieve, hence using the `<button>` element above. A lot of accessibility comes for free when you take this approach, since browsers add many (or all) of the behaviours expected by the user.

If you were to do the above using `<div>` and `<span>` elements, you need to enable appropriate keyboard focus and handle both mouse and keyboard events.

```
<div role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="0">Home</div>
```

The W3C's [WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/) details approaches and expectations for common design patterns. For example, if you have several top-level items to choose from, you would want to use a [Navigation Menubar](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/menubar/menubar-1/menubar-1.html).

Based on the Codepen example, **what you are looking for** is probably something like a [Menu Button](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/menu-button/menu-button-actions.html) (or this [alternative Menu Buttons tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/11/building-accessible-menu-systems/)), since you only requite a single dropdown menu rather than a whole menubar. This would produce something like the following:

```
<button aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">Story type</button>
<div role="menu">
  <button role="menuitem">Home</button>
  <button role="menuitem">All</button>
  <button role="menuitem">News and media</button>
  <button role="menuitem">Analysis</button>
  <button role="menuitem">Press releases</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like you are mixing things. A menu button, which opens the menu, should have `aria-haspopup="true"` and then the menu items of the opened menu should have `role="menuitem"`

Comment: For the Codepen example, you are correct – the button that opens the single menu requires the `aria-haspopup` attribute. But the example I use to make the point is still valid, as per the W3C's [ARIA menubar example](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/menubar/menubar-1/menubar-1.html) – the ARIA properties must be on the same element. As I said in my solution, the original author is most likely looking for a Menu Button implementation.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more calirity on what I'm actually suggesting, as well as explaining some important points on how ARIA attributes are expected to work.